# How to Rename Files in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I want to rename all files in selected directory using rename command or move command from :

```
_02_mp3_cbr_320.m4a?anghakamitoken=sc245ae5a454547.5
_02_mp3_fsgsfsdfsfdfdsfcbr_320.m4a?anghakamitoken=sc245.ae5a
```

to

```
1.m4a
2.m4a
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: write your [shell script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script). Learn about [gawk(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gawk.1.html), [rename(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html), [bash(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html). SO is not a *do-my-homework* or *write-my-script* service. So your question is **off-topic** (without any [MCVE]) on SO.

Comment: So what did you try?

Comment: thank you all it works fine

Answer (score 1):

If those files always have a sheme like this:

> `_02_mp3_` * `_320.m4a?anghakamitoken=` *

You can do it like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
COUNT=0
for f in ./"_02_mp3_"*"_320.m4a?anghakamitoken="*; do
    mv $f "$((++COUNT)).m4a"
done
```

This will result in

> 1.m4a 
>   2.m4a

Assuming the initial files are in the same directory as the bash script.

Comment: You can merge the two commands in the loop with `$((++COUNT))`

Comment: @iBug True, edited the answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this with **GNU Parallel**. it basically uses **GNU Parallel**'s job number (`{#}`) as the number for renaming:

```
parallel --dry-run -k mv {} {#}.m4a ::: *m4a*
```

**Sample Output**

```
mv _02_mp3_cbr_320.m4a\?anghakamitoken\=sc245ae5a454547.5 1.m4a
mv _02_mp3_fsgsfsdfsfdfdsfcbr_320.m4a\?anghakamitoken\=sc245.ae5a 2.m4a
```

If the commands look correct, remove the `--dry-run` part and run it again. The `-k` keeps the output in order. The `{}` refers to the current file.

Make a backup before using any commands you are unfamiliar with...

Answer (score -1):

To rename any file in Linux using mv (move) command:
mv   (cfr. "man mv")

In this case, you need to enter the following lines on the command line:

$mv _02_mp3_cbr_320.m4a?anghakamitoken=sc245ae5a454547.5 1.m4a

$mv _02_mp3_fsgsfsdfsfdfdsfcbr_320.m4a?anghakamitoken=sc245.ae5a 1.m4a

It is important that you refer to the manual when you know the command you must use, to understand how to use it.